# NodeJs + Mongo db unable to wait result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm using NodeJs and MongoDB to dev a Web Api.
I encounter the problem that my await statements are not being awaited...

Here is a code example and the output, it makes no sense to me..

**Code**

```
   async find_nearby_places(lng, lat, tag, maxDistance) {
    let results = [];

    await MongoClient.connect(url, async function (err, db) {
        let places= db.db(db_name).collection(collection_places);

        let nearbyplaces = places.find({
            "location":
                {
                    $near:
                        {
                            $geometry: {
                                coordinates: [lng, lat]
                            },
                            $maxDistance: maxDistance
                        }
                },
            "tags": {
                $in: [tag]
            }
        });

        await nearbyplaces.toArray().then(
            async placeArray => {
                placeArray.forEach(place => {
                    console.log("API: FOUND place");
                    results.push(placeModel.ToplaceModel(place))
                });
                await db.close();
            });
        console.log(' ---------------------- DONE')
    });
    console.log(" ---------------------- EXIT");
}
```

**Output**

```
 ---------------------- EXIT 
API: FOUND place 
API: FOUND place 
---------------------- DONE
```

**Expected output**

```
API: FOUND place
API: FOUND place
 ---------------------- DONE
 ---------------------- EXIT
```

Comment: Your using the callback version of connect,..

Comment: Yes, but that should be synchronous right? But it behaves async...

Comment: `Yes, but that should be synchronous right?` Docs say -> `Returns:
Promise if no callback passed `..  So No..

Comment: Also, if your using async/await, then use it.  Why use a callback in the first place.. just do -> `const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);`  and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Await only waits if a promise is returned, for functions with callbacks, new promise has to be defined.

```
async find_nearby_places() {

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, async function (err, db) {
       //Do tasks
       Promise.resolve()
    }
  })
}
```

The resolution can be done with any value, in which case the promise will give back that returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `find_nearby_places` is an `async` function .
. 
then your other actions except `console.log(" ---------------------- EXIT");` are on `await` mode..

Soo this line `console.log(" ---------------------- EXIT");` never wait for to execute. but other `actions` are in `await` mode.so they are to be executed `one by one` as long as to be waited